# Data still not inserting in SQLITE DB?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
    import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('./sampledb.db')
print("Opened database successfully")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (name TEXT, number INTEGER)')
print("Created table");
cur.execute('INSERT INTO person (name, number) VALUES (\'sam\', 15 )')
print('Inserted data')
cur.close()
```

I am using python;
This creates the database table and even prints the line **after the INSERT** which is

```
 print('Inserted data')
```

But there is still no data, what is going wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have to commit the changes for it to reflect in database.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('./sampledb.db')
print("Opened database successfully")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (name TEXT, number INTEGER)')
print("Created table");
cur.execute('INSERT INTO person (name, number) VALUES (\'sam\', 15 )')
print('Inserted data')
conn.commit()
cur.close()
```